# R - multiple linear regression plot analyzing

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

I'm having troubles analyzing the plots resulting from multiple linear regression. Can someone explain briefly what do these plot mean and what are the assumptions of the multplie linear regression? Thank you so much. 
[image]

Comment: Asked and answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181939/28500). Please read that question, answer and associated links. If questions remain, please edit this question to specify what is still unclear.

Comment: One quick way to remember the major assumptions of multiple linear regression is to remember the acronym LINE: Linearity, Independence, Normality and Equal Variance/Variability.